# Home page link in tag pop-up

Tags: feature-request, tags, hyperlinks, homepage

Recently I found myself using [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) links more often, e.g. `[tag:spring]` rather than a normal link to library/product/framework home page like `[Spring](http://www.springsource.org/)`. This is much more convenient for me. However when the reader actually wants to browse to the home page, he must open tag info page and find the link *somewhere*. My suggestion is to add dedicated home page link field to tag info:

[image: tag info]

and expose that link on tag pop-up:

[image]

Most of the tags on [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) are either languages/products/libraries that have a single official web page. In other case (like [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) or [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)) we can simply link to Wikipedia.

Comment: I don't like your mockup. The style and positioning of the "homepage" link makes it look like something on or related to Stack Overflow, when it's really linking to an external page, the content of which we have absolutely no control over.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just go the simple route...make a link in the text that is clickable, then have that link available to be clicked on the popup?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, yes, before anyone says anything, I typed the wrong URL in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that a direct link would be useful in that box. Maybe if it got shortened to just "website" or "home" or maybe a little house icon in the bottom right corner so it wasn't as long (you're really pushing for space there). However, I would be very against linking to Wikipedia pages for those tags which did not have an official website. Why would we want to link to someone else's wiki page when we have **our own wiki page** for each tag?

Also, adding another box in the edit screen probably won't happen. If it got implemented, it should probably use the secret comment syntax `<!-- website: http://www.example.com -->` to identify what the official website is, similar to the `<!-- language -->` syntax in posts and the `<!-- summary -->` syntax in profiles.